# How to concatenate leading zeros on linked cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

**Sheet A (customers)**
Over 2,000 customer listed

- 07.001 is the first customer with the last name beginning with "G"
- 07.056 is the 56th customer with the last name beginning with "G"

**Sheet B   (invoices)**

| Label | Cell | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer No | B317 | 07.056 |
| Project No | J317 | 3510 |
| Invoice No | A317 | 4620 |

****Sheet C** (ledger entry)**

> =CONCATENATE('Sheet B'!B317,"-",'Sheet B'!J317," ",'Sheet B'!A317)

```
 Result
   7.056-3510 4620

 Desired
   07.056-3510 4620
```

**Question:**

Within Sheet C, how to format the link to: 'Sheet B'!B317
to include the leading zero?

I've read numerous solutions that reference using the TEXT function, but I cannot figure-out how to apply it to my situation on Sheet C, or even if that is the simplest solution.

Comment: look into the TEXT funtion: `=CONCATENATE(TEXT('Sheet B'!B317,"00.000"),"-",'Sheet B'!J317," ",'Sheet B'!A317)`

Comment: For me, your fomula give your desired result.

Comment: Change the Sheet B Value column to TEXT cell format.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Sheet B'!B317` cell , put `'07.056` inside the cell (notice the extra) `'`. Then the original formula should be working just fine.

Please share if it works/not..

Comment: I'm not sure how easy is it for 2000 entries

Comment: @MátéJuhász the OP is not responding to @ ScottCraner suggestion, I'm just trying to open up another options. /(^_^)